# xcode shows the error Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, xcode7, unity3d-2dtools

When i run a unity game in xcode i got the following error

```
"UnityPause(bool)", referenced from:
  -[EtceteraManager showViewControllerModallyInWrapper:] in    EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager dismissWrappedController] in EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager showAlertWithTitle:message:buttons:] in EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager showPromptWithTitle:message:placeHolder:autocorrect:] in EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager showPromptWithTitle:message:placeHolder1:placeHolder2:autocorrect:] in  EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager showWebControllerWithUrl:showingControls:] in  EtceteraManager.o
  -[EtceteraManager popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:] in      EtceteraManager.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether library containing EtceteraManager class is linked with your project. 
If yes then check for architecture of library using **file** command on terminal.

> `file $PATH_TO_LIB`

The architecture should be same as on project's architecture settings.